# Comma after “viz.” in “viz.(,) that”?

Tags: american-english, commas, subordinate-clauses, abbreviations, latin

Concerning the usage of “viz.” in American English, in [ODO](http://www.lexico.com/en/definition/viz.) we find examples with and without the comma after “viz.” when a “that”-introduced clause follows:

> This leads many people towards the second, more public-minded response: viz. that a life can be made meaningful by dedicating it wholly or partially towards helping others.

> But a certain causal process – viz., that which standardly takes place when we say that so-and-so sees such-and-such – must occur.

> The demand for social change offers them but one alternative, viz., that of upholding the violent method or of maintaining the status quo.

When do we write “viz. that” and when “viz., that”?

Comment: It's possibly that `viz.` without comma is being used as an equivalent to "that is to say", and `viz.,` with the comma is being used as an equivalent to "namely,"

Comment: "Concerning the usage of “viz.” in American English" - first of all, Lexico's US and UK editions aren't as clearly distinct as you might think - they often share lists of example sentences.  So many of the examples quoted might be from British usage.  Secondly, Lexico actually notes that "viz." is "mainly British" anyway.

Comment: @myacorn Perhaps. Or it could just be variation among different sources using different norms or different style guides.

Comment: I had a manager who used 'videlicet'. I think he wanted to impress people.

Comment: @rjpond Thanks, yes, we know that Lexico's data isn't ideal. E.g., the second example containing “that which” is hard to digest. So I'd be happy to get better examples.

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey Using “viz.” in my case was a suggestion from an editor. In any case, since it's shorter than “that is to say” and “namely”, and since I'm low on space, I'm overly happy to use “viz.”. If I can impress people with it, so better.

Comment: I wouldn't be rushing to copy anyone who could write 'standardly'.

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey It seems a strange adverb to me, but it exists anyway: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/standardly , https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/standardly